# How to send model id to ActiveFrom field

Tags: yii2

I have a view team/view where I have details for the team (from the model Team).

views/team/view.php:

```
<?php
    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\widgets\DetailView;
    use yii\grid\GridView;
    use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
    use app\models\Pt;    

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model app\models\Team */

    $this->title = $model->name;
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Teams', 'url' => ['index']];
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    ?>
    <div class="team-view">

        <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>    
        <p>
            <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data' => [
                    'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]) ?> 
        </p>

        <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [              
                'tournament.name',
                'teamindex',
                'region.name',       
                'rank',
            ],
        ]) ?>

    <?= Html::a('add players to the team', ['pt/create'], ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) ?>   
    </div>
```

Last link is a link button to add players to the team: `<?= Html::a('add players to the team', ['pt/create'], ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) ?>`

In views/pt/create I have an ActiveForm with fields: team (dropdown list), player (dropdown list). So, if I want to add a player to the team I should choose the team's name from a looong dropdown list and then choose a player (and some player options..).

Here is views/pt/create.php:

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model app\models\Pt */

    $this->title = 'Add players to the team';
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Players in teams', 'url' => ['index']];
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    ?>
    <div class="pt-create">

        <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>    
        <?= $this->render('_form', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]) ?>  
    </div>
```

Here is views/pt/_form.php:

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
    use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
    use app\models\Player;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;


    /* @var $this yii\web\View */
    /* @var $model app\models\Pt */
    /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
    ?>

    <div class="pt-form">

        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'owner-form']); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'team_id')->dropDownList($model->teamList) ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'player_id')
            ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Player::find()->joinWith('category')
                ->orderBy(['lastname'=>SORT_ASC])->all(), 'id', 'lastname'));
        ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Add' : 'Update', ['class' => $model
        ->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

I want like this: when I am on http://localhost/myproject/web/team/100 I click on that button `<?= Html::a('add players to the team', ['pt/create'], ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) ?>`

and go to pt/create where in the field team already defined team_id =100 and so I need to input only player.

How can I do that? I know this is simple but I'm still learning.

PS: Models `Team` and `Pt` have relations,

models/Team.php

```
public function getPt()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pt::className(), ['team_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create  a proper cation for create  the player with the id_team already assigned (or you can modify the original create)

```
    /**
   * Creates a new Palyer model assigning the id_team.
   * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function actionCreateForTeam(id_team)
  {
      $model = new Player();

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
          return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
      } else {
          $model->id_team = $id_team
          return $this->render('create', [
              'model' => $model,
          ]);
      }
  }
```

Then  send the proper id_team

```
  Html::a('add players to the team', ['pt/create-for-teaam', 'id_team'=> $model->team_id], 
   ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Comment: I meant easy but not so easy. pt/create uses its own model Pt. And field team uses model Team. Both models have relations.

Comment: update you question and add you related controller/action code and create view code

Comment: I did. This is my first app so probably it contains mistakes (but it works)

Comment: I can't understand why is it the Player model.. I try to explain my situation more clear

Comment: I have 3 models: Player (which is the table with players), Team (which is the table of teams). These 2 models have relations many-to-many (during the season one player can play in many teams and one team can include many players). So I have third model - Pt (short for 'players-teams'), which is a table in db with 2 fields: team_id (foreign to team.id) and player_id(foreign key - player.id).

Comment: I have an ActiveForm in the view views/pt/create (which is based on model Pt) with 2 dropdownlists: 'choose player' and 'choose team'. When I choose some team and some player I create a row in database, for exampe 125 (player_id) - 345 (team_id). It works.

Comment: And what I need. I need to go to the view views/team/view to see team details. For example, it is team "Barcelona".  On that page I need a link to my views/pt/create. I made it - but when I click on it I need to choose with 2 dropdownlists: 'choose player' and 'choose team'. And I want to have first dropdownlist ('choose player') already defined to the team "Barcelona" (because I came to that page from the page of team 'Barcelona'). 
I try to explain it more clear but I have not much experience in it and please try to understand me. :)

Comment: Finally I found the solution in one of the great Yii2 books. The 
scaisEdge's comment was useful too, thanks.